# Using FTS3/4 Table based on Select Statements from Normal Table

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

In my app, I'm developing in Android, I have a Sqlite Table called *Transactions*, with these fields:

```
_Id | Date | Value | Notes
```

I already have a ListView showing results filtering by  Date (for example):

`Select * FROM Transacions WHERE Date BETWEEN '2016-04-25' AND '2016-05-14'`

It works fine, but I want to implement a SearchView to search transactions between a custom date have in field *Notes*, some text typed in SearchView.
I read about adding a SearchView, and the best way to implement to search is using a FTS3 or FTS4 Table, allowing the user, for example, type "SUPERMARKET" and find a Transaction where the Notes have this text.
The problem appears because a FTS table is slow to perform WHERE conditions (like the above, to filter date)...

How can I implement both Filtering date, using `WHERE date BETWEEN ... and ...`, and filtering text Notes with the performance of a FTS Table?

- If it is not possible to do so, is it a good idea to have a query like this:

`Select * FROM Transacions WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2016-04-25' AND '2016-05-14) AND Notes LIKE '%text%''`?

Comment: "is it a good idea to have a query like this" -- that will be seriously slow. Off the cuff, a join or a sub-select might be the best option, though I haven't played around with this scenario just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not think of an FTS table as a table, but as an index.

With the notes indexed like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Transactions_FTS USING FTS4(Notes);
```

you would have to ensure  that the IDs of both tables match, and could then combine the tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2016-04-25' AND '2016-05-14'
  AND _Id IN (SELECT docid
              FROM Transactions_FTS
              WHERE Notes MATCH 'supermarket');
```

or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
JOIN Transactions_FTS ON Transactions._Id = Transactions_FTS.docid
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2016-04-25' AND '2016-05-14'
  AND Transactions_FTS.Notes MATCH 'supermarket';
```

(If you care about the amount of storage used, consider an [external content FTS table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2).)

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Actually, the second option seems more suitable to me, however I have to change other methods (update, insert...) to work with the fts and the normal table. To not change so much my code, I created dynamically in Activity, a fts with the data filtered in transactions, so when user starts search for some text, in fact it is using fts match, but the values alredy contained in between date... from other table